# The Euler-Lagrange first integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How to calculate $\frac{d\phi}{dz}$ from following equation:
$$A\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}+\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)=0,$$
where $A$ is a constant?

Comment: $\int \frac1{\sin x \cos x}dx$

Comment: @Math-fun How is that relevant?

Comment: @Dylan ups, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A\frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}+\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)=0,$$
Substitute $$p=\frac {d \phi}{dz} \implies \frac{d^2\phi}{dz^2}=p\frac {dp} {d \phi} $$
$$App'=-\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)$$
$$A\int pdp=-\frac 12\int \sin(2\phi) d\phi$$
$$Ap^2= \frac 12\cos (2\phi) +K_1$$
$$\frac {d \phi}{dz} =\pm \sqrt {\frac {\cos (2\phi) +K_1} {2A}}$$
$$.......$$

@tgram
$$Ap^2= \frac 12\cos (2\phi) +K_1$$
note that 
$$\cos (2\phi)=2\cos^2 \phi -1=2(1-\sin^2 \phi )-1=1-2\sin^2 \phi$$
The constant $K_1$ absorb all the constants...

And $$p=\frac {d \phi}{dz}$$

Comment: In answer sheet it says that the solution is $\left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2=\frac{1}{A}\left(\frac{1}{C^2}-\sin^2(\phi)\right)$ (I assume $C$ comes from integration).

Comment: It cant be $A^2$ it's A .... you can change the sin function by $1-\cos^2 \phi$ the constant will absorb the number 1 @TGram

Comment: @TGram I added some line you should get the same result as that of your book

Comment: Thanks, however I am still a bit confused regarding the origin of $C^2$.

Comment: @TGram it's just a constant thats all writing it $1/C$ or C dosent change that much

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $\frac{d\phi}{dz}$ and then integrate (using the chain rule to help...).

Answer (score 0):

Since $2A\phi'\phi''+\phi'\sin 2\phi=0$, $C:=A\phi'^2-\frac{1}{2}\cos 2\phi$ is constant. In particular $z=\int\dfrac{d\phi}{\sqrt{(C+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2\phi)/A}}$, which you can reduce to an [elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind). Inverting this gives $\phi$ in terms of $z$, or if you just want $\phi'=(dz/d\phi)^{-1}$ in terms of $\phi$ no elliptic integrals are needed.

Comment: In answer sheet it says that the solution is $\left(\frac{d\phi}{dz}\right)^2=\frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{1}{C^2}-\sin^2(\phi)\right)$ (I assume $C$ comes from integration).

Comment: @TGram I can't see how a $1/A^2$ ended up in there; either that exponent is a misprint on their part, or in your question you copied out the problem without it. But their answer is basically mine; note $\frac{1}{2}\cos 2\phi=\frac{1}{2}-\sin^2\phi$. This is in fact how it reduces to using an elliptic integral.

Comment: I wrongly copied solution. It should solely by $A$

Answer (score 0):

$$
A\phi'\phi'' +\cos\phi\sin\phi\phi' = 0\Rightarrow \frac 12A(\phi'^2)'+\frac 12(\sin^2\phi)' = 0
$$

hence

$$
A\phi'^2+\sin^2\phi = C_1\Rightarrow \phi' = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}\sqrt{C_1-\sin^2\phi}
$$